# How to distinguish connect-timeout and socket-timeout in ZuulFallbackProvider?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, fallback

I am using ZuulFallbackProvider to handle fallback and would like to know how to distinguish one root cause from another, such as connect-timeout and socket-timeout. However, I am unable to find a lead by only examing the RequestContext in getBody(). Any advice is appreciated.

I also left the same question on git:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/2347

Answer (score 1):

In Edgware (as of yet unreleased) the new `FallbackProvider` provides `fallbackResponse(Throwable cause)`. You should be able to inspect the `cause` to find out.

Comment: any idea when will a SR happen? and any suggestion to achieve same goal before Edgware.SR1 is released? Thank you.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones?direction=asc&sort=due_date&state=open for when Edgware.RELEASE is due. I don't have an answer in the meantime.